# Loading comma separated .csv file into database

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I was trying to load a .csv file into my database. It was a comma delimited file and for one of the columns there is a comma(,) in between the data just like Texas,Houston can some one help me how to get rid of the comma in between. the package which i have created recognizing the value after the comma as a new column but it should not be like that. Can any of the guys help me in this. I was getting error in the Flat file source itself. I thought of using Derived column but the package is failing at the source point itself.

Comment: If the column _always_ contains both a republic and a city then just import to two columns and corrupt, er, recombine the data afterwards.  Or leave it split apart so that it is more useful.

Answer (score -1):

Well some "comma" delimited files have ,"something or other", when there is a string and only use ,numeric_value, when its a number type. If your file is like this then you can preprocess your file changing ," for some (other) rare character, and similarly ", then replace the , if it occurs between the two rare characters. Or you can count the comma in any line and if its greater than the number pf delimited columns, manually frocess the exceptions

Comment: Thanks guys finally i solved this by changing   Text qualifier: "